# how can i get auth user or any session in the my custom class and provider?

Tags: php, laravel, user-controls, provider, construct

i have to get the company which user chooses but i can't get user data in my class and provider boot function .

user can have more than one company so user have to choose a company for some operations. But as i said , i can't get the company which user chooses.

Like this :

```
 public function boot()
    {

        $user = Auth::user();

        dd( $user ); // return null;

        $bid = new Bid();
        $show = $bid->check();
        Blade::directive('bid',function() use($show){
            return "<?php if( $show ) { ?>";
        });

        Blade::directive('endbid',function(){
            return '<?php } ?>';
        });
    }
```

My other class :

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Buying\Package;

use App\Services\Buying\Package\PackageInterface;
use App\Models\Company\Company;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class PackageBuying extends PackageQuery implements PackageInterface
{
    private $company_id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        dd( $user ); // return null

        $this->setCompanyId($this->company_id);
    }

    public function setSession( Request $request )
    {
        $request->session()->get('selected-company');
    }

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->company_id;
    }

    public function package()
    {
        if ( $this->check() ) {
            return $this->getPackage($this->company())->first();
        }

        return [];
    }

    public function features()
    {
        return (object)json_decode( $this->package()->features );
    }

    public function importantFeatures()
    {
        return (object)json_decode( $this->package()->important_features );
    }

    public function active()
    {
        return (bool) $this->getPackage()->firstOrFail()->active;
    }
}
```

Actually if i got user data in the provider boot function , i could send data to my class .

May you please help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code inside your construct function to calMethod function like this

```php
public function callAction( $method, $parameters ) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        dd( $user ); // return null
        $this->setCompanyId($this->company_id);
        return parent::callAction( $method, $parameters );
    }
```

Comment: I used like this :

private $company_id;
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $test = $this->callAction(Auth::user());

        dd($test);
        
        $this->setCompanyId($this->company_id);
    }

    public function callAction($method) {
        return parent::callAction( $method );
    }

but i got an error .

Comment: I think callAction is a hook function, so you should overwrite this function to do some think before action to be run. And the `__construct` function of Controller would be run very soon, before all middleware to be done, before the app is **booted**